# Woocommerce Add To Cart redirect to Checkout not working

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I'm trying to redirect people who click on the add to cart button to the checkout page directly. The add to cart button only is adding the product to cart but not redirecting at all.

I've tried to put the WooCommerce setting on auto
https://gyazo.com/d5357f81ccb48723ea72125a3368dd81

I'm using the Theme Sartre on my website but another website with the same theme is working well so i'm confused.

The only bit of code i've added is https://gyazo.com/6d13ed2ebc037b8576dcb911a1328241 in the function.php file of my theme.

My website doesn't seem to show any error while i'm pressing Add to Cart 
https://chase-lab.com/

I'm using the latest version of woocommerce Version 3.6.1

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried to disable other plugins? Have you tried to change/reinstall that theme? (maybe some files got corrupted)

Comment: Yes I did try. When I activate the default Theme Twenty Seventeen the redirection works fine so I thought it was the Theme but why does it works on my other website ?

Comment: Your theme using AJAX and it overrides woocommerce functionality. Check Theme options page - And turn off ajax add to cart functionality.

Comment: You're a Legend :)
 It was the AJAX of the theme. I found a way to desactivate it, not the perfect one though could only do it by pressing NO on the ThemeMountain Theme Options "Ues ThemeMountain Ajax Cart Nav Menu". Also it desactivate the cart button with notification in the nav bar. Find a way to add a cart but without notification. The redirection works fine now though so thank you !